# PHP MVC: How to dispaly content via text not id values through the URL

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am used to creating small php mvc structures etc and relying on passing the id of the item i need to display:

```
   www.asite.co.uk/controller/method/IDnumber
```

But I see a lot of sites use say the title of a page within the URL.

```
   www.asite.co.uk/controller/this-is-a-title
    www.asite.co.uk/controller/i-am-another-section/this-is-a-title
```

MY question is its easy to get the contents via the ID method but who would you work it to use the text method to retrieve the data / content you require.

Initially I would think of removing the '-' separators then searching the 'title' field say for the result, but not sure if there would be a better/easier way.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to tell you that the text in url is just name of the page. As I also work in MVC so i know that it is only a page name, the requested data is in post method or stored in sessions which are taken forward to the page and after they are made in use, they are destroyed.

Comment: Hi anuj arora, thakns for this understanding it correctly, instead of passing the page id with the url, set a temp session using the number  then set the pages title to be the text for readability.  If so great and thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use a column in my table content called "slug" and find the content searching by this column. This column needs to be unique, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display header differently, do it via htaccess:
http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Great Link but I already use the htaccess for redirection etc, but that link is a good tut, thanks for the answer.